# Add SWT context menu in SWT Table with Shortcut Keys

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am trying to add a context menu on SWT Table with the Key Name.
Context Menu is coming properly but I am not able to set the key name as we can mention as a "sequence" in Menu Contribution.
I am not using Menu Contribution but using a MenuItem.

Here is my code.

```
final MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);   
item.setText(save);
item.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            //saveFunction
        }
 });
```

This is working but I want to add the Key name also with the name of Menu something like this:

[image]

Can anyone please help me as I can not use MenuContribution.

Comment: Is this just a plain SWT app or is it in an Eclipse plug-in? Eclipse provides extra features for this sort of thing in plug-ins.

Comment: It is a eclipse plugin app but I am not creating the menus of this table using plugin.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MenuItem.setAccelerator` to set the key for the menu item:

```java
item.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 | 'S');
```

Note that this is only active when the menu is shown, if the menu is not shown you would need to use a key listener. I have used the `SWT.MOD1` modifier here rather than `SWT.CTRL` so that the key will be the correct <kbd>⌘+S</kbd> on macOS.

On platforms that don't automatically add the accelerator text you can get set the text using:

```java
String acceleratorText = Action.convertAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 | 'S');

item.setText(save + '\t' + acceleratorText);
```

Here `Action` is `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action`.

In an Eclipse plug-in you should probably be using a retargetable action to integrate with the standard save code.

Comment: SetAccelerator is kind a shortcut key of the menu that is working.
But I meant with the text of Key (Ctrl +S) which is visible with the text of menu.
I also want to show this key sequence with the menu text but I  do **not** want to just set it with the menuItem.setText(Save    Ctrl+S) as there can be multiple menus with different size of names and keys.
So, I am looking for some method to save the key sequence with the text.

Comment: The key text is shown on macOS, I don't know what other OSs do. Another reason to use the proper Eclipse plug-in APIs which should get this right.

Comment: I have added the code the used by `ActionContributionItem` to get the accelerator text

Comment: Thank You very much. Action.convertAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 | 'S'); is working.